# Why is the winner still awarded $1 million U.S.dollars?

Tags: reality-tv, survivor

When [*Survivor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivor_(U.S._TV_series)) premiered on May 31, 2000, the grand prize offered to the winner was $1 million U.S. dollars.

Survivor is now in it's 33rd season after airing for 16 years and still offers the same grand prize of $1 million U.S. dollars to the winner.

According to this [article](http://www.hollywood.com/tv/how-much-are-reality-show-prizes-really-worth-57298355/) from 2012, the winner of Survivor would take home an estimated $750,000 U.S. dollars after taxes when the show first premiered.  As of 2012, the estimated take home for the winner is approximately $540,000 U.S. dollars due to inflation.  (Excluding 1st season winner, Richard Hatch who went to jail for failing to pay taxes on his winnings)

**Why has the grand prize cash award remained the same amount after 16 years?**

Comment: Because it's a symbolic amount, and still a big amount with or without the inflation? Also, it "lures" people, when in fact they earn less?

Comment: I agree, it's just simpler with a round number that still [*sounds*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKKHSAE1gIs) impressive; *The Amazing Race* hasn't changed it either. Plus, a show with declining ratings is supposed to cost *less*, not more. ;)

Comment: Because Americans have historically not believed in correcting for inflation. See the lack of increase in minimum wage, lack of cost of life increases, no raises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simple answer is **they don't need to increase the purse** to get contestants. They are clearly getting a broad enough applicant pool to select the contestants they want. Plus you should consider that after 30+ seasons there is an increased fame factor, so people are drawn by money AND fame. Fame can be a powerful motivator. There was a show in the UK called *Nothing but the Truth* whose format has been copied in other countries that [had its Greek version taken off the air](http://www.ukgameshows.com/ukgs/Nothing_But_the_Truth) "for encouraging contestants to "humiliate themselves for a reward", with "no regard for the players' decency or the effects on the social lives of their families"." *Survivor* clearly isn't in that same class but it does go to show that people will do crazy things for less money than offered by *Survivor* on the TV.

Also I think it is important to note that $500k net isn't peanuts. There are shows like *Jeopardy!* that have been on the air for ages, with lower payouts, and *Jeopardy!* [hasn't bumped payouts since 2001](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeopardy!). People go on *Jeopardy!* mostly for factors besides money, although I'm pretty sure the money helps. I think it is reasonable to say contestants on *Survivor* compete for more than just the paycheck.

Comment: Hmmmm...excellent points!